# Subset in Random Forest

Tags: data-mining, random-forest

In Random forest..each subset is taken randomly to build tree. But how can we gaurentee that we are taking a unique subset.

If my N = 2, 2 random samples to be generated to build the tree. As data is chosen randomly same data can enter into other subset. How can we make sure to do that .

Is there any mechanism for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

There is no reason to make them disjoint. if you only have little data, you may need to consider 90% every time, for example.

Comment: ok . so if I have a large amount of data how can I make sure that each subset/seed is a unique set?